# URL + Show Hidden Div

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, redirect, permalinks

how can i redirect page using custom link
ex:-

```
wc_get_template( 'myaccount/dashboard.php', array(
    'current_user' => get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() ),
) );
```

and i have hidden div in myaccount page.

```
<div class="alert success">
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <strong>Registration Success!</strong> Check Email.
</div>
```

how to show div button if the following link is
`[register->myaccount]`

and if i use another link, like
`[login->myaccount]`

The div will hide again.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' )."?base=register" );
```

and html like below

```
<div class="alert success" style="<?php echo (isset($_GET['base']) && $_GET['base'] == "register") ? 'display:block' : 'display:none' ; ?>">
    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <strong>Registration Success!</strong> Check Email.
</div>
```

Comment: the second way i used, the page is blank

Comment: sory, i edited the question. but the result is blank.
can i use jQuery? i never used it before.

Comment: give me URL which will show in the address bar after a redirect

Comment: myaccount/dashboard.php
but in woocommerce theme, the code is like this
wc_get_template( 'myaccount/dashboard.php', array(
    'current_user' => get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() ),
) );

Comment: if i make div like this <div class="alert success" style="<?php echo (isset($_GET['base']) && $_GET['base'] == "register"); ?>"> how can i make this div show just once after registration with jquery?